# Synology File Station API C#

Tags: c#, api, synology

I encounter a trouble with the file station API using RestSharp
I would like to upload a file, I follow the document describe in the official API doc ( [here](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf) )

There is my code :

```
    private const string url_auth = "/webapi/entry.cgi";


    public Upload()
    {
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"/Users/XXXXXX/Downloads/file.csv");


        var client = new RestClient(SynSettings.DSM);
        var request = new RestRequest(url_auth);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        request.Method = Method.POST;

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", $"multipart/form-data; boundary={Guid.NewGuid()}");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", $"{data.Length}");

        request.AddQueryParameter("api", "SYNO.FileStation.Upload");
        request.AddQueryParameter("method", "upload");
        request.AddQueryParameter("version", "2");

        request.AddQueryParameter("_sid", $"{SynSettings.Sid}");
        //request.("", $"{SynSettings.Sid}");

        request.AddParameter("api", "SYNO.FileStation.Upload", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("version", "2", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("method", "upload", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("path", "/ActiveBackupforBusiness", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("create_parents", "false", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

        request.AddFileBytes("file", data, "file.csv", "application/octet-stream");

        Console.WriteLine(client.BuildUri(request));
        var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(queryResult.Content);

    }
```

Thanks for your help

**Update 1**

The first step, I call the API to get the SID, after this I save it to use it every time with the parameter "_sid"

When I try to upload a file, the server API respond with :
{"error":{"code":401},"success":false}

I don't understand what's wrong with my code

Comment: `I encounter a trouble with the file station API using RestSharp I would like to upload a file`, you never explained the trouble's you are having. Please update your post to include such details.

Comment: Are you aware what 401 means? This is a quick lookup.

Comment: yes and no the doc say : 401 - Unknown error of file operation
Is not a proper answer ..

Answer (score 0):

I used it and it works for me. I am using RestSharp 106.15.0, though it isn't working for newer versions.

```
var path = @"C:\test.txt";
var file = new FileInfo(path);
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("_sid", _session.Sid, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("api", "SYNO.FileStation.Upload", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("version", "2", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("method", "upload", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("path", destinationFilePath);
request.AddParameter("overwrite", overwrite);

request.AddFile(file.Name, file.FullName);
var client = new RestClient("https://YOUR_HOST/webapi/entry.cgi");

var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;
```